# UIWebview - could not open the password protected .xlsx,.docx and .ppt

Tags: ios, uiwebview, xlsx

I have tried to open `(using loadData/loadRequest methods of webview)` the password protected files in my web view controller. I can open the password protected pdf and zip files. it works fine. But When I tried to open the other password protected files it shows the error.

```
(unable to read document).
```

If i have tried to open that file in Safari, there also i am getting the same error.
But It works fine in iPad mail native app.

Please guide me. What is problem ?

Whenever i have tried to open the password protected pdf/ppt files , it return below EXCEPTION

```
**EXCEPTION SFUZipEndOfCentralDirectoryError: Could not find the end of central directory record**
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through UIWebView , we cannot open any password protected files except PDF. If you want to open the password protected files, use **QLPreviewcontroller**. It will work perfectly

Comment: QLPreviewcontroller does work well, however, it seems that QLPreviewcontroller does not support developers customise user interactions. For example, if I want pop an alert if I touch the screen. I do not how to monitor the user touches.

Answer (score 1):

You can't open password protected zip or pdf until unlock it.

```
CGPDFDocumentUnlockWithPassword(doc, pass).
```

i have not tried this but i hope this will help for you.

Comment: Thanks Sanjay.Pdf and zip no problem. It works fine. When I have tried to open .xlsx/.docx files, those could not open.